# javascript remove duplicate decimal points in number input

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Need to prevent people from accidentally typing 2 decimal places in a set of type=number input fields with step=any. I have tried the following to no avail.

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=number]').keyup(function(){
        var newval=$(this).val().split('..').join('.');
        $(this).val(newval);
    });
});


$(function(){
    $('input[type=number]').keyup(function(){
        var newval=$(this).val().replace('..','.');
        $(this).val(newval);
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('input[type=number]').keyup(function(){
        var newval=$(this).val().replace(/\.\./g,'.');
        $(this).val(newval);
    });
});
```

all of these just blank out the value, or do nothing at all and the duplicate decimals remain.

https://jsfiddle.net/uLayjmkv/

Comment: Some sample input/output of what you expect would be helpful in understanding your question.

Comment: So if my sales people put in "1..35" instead of "1.35"  it needs to remove the duplicate decimal

Comment: How will you correct it if they type "11.35" instead of "1.35"?

Comment: @James he wouldn't?  that doesn't contain duplicate decimals.

Comment: You have a `:` at the end of your code instead of `;`

Comment: The problem is that the input is `"type=number"`, the value of 1 and 1. are both 1. If you want to do something regex like you will need to use `"type=text"` (which you could allow only numbers in with a regex).

Comment: For `type=number`, the value of the input is converted by the browser to a number. If you type something that isn't a number, the value is an empty string, not what they typed. There doesn't seem to be a way to get the actual input.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps? Using type 'text' not 'number'

```js
let last = '';

document.getElementById('me').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const match = e.target.value.match(/[-+]?\d*\.?\d*/);
  if (match || e.target.value === '') {
    last = match ? match[0] : '';
  }

  e.target.value = last;
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="me" type="text" />
```

Seems to work ok for me on chrome 58. Don't know if there are any further edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the input everyone, what i ended up doing is on keyup, change attr "type" to "text", run the replace(), and then change it back to a "number".